# How to get the operation time of Git command?

Tags: git, command-line

I want to blame a Git operation history in my repository to know when the Git operations happen, e.g. when does the last `git fetch` and/or `git rebase` happen?

Since there are other schedule scripts to trigger those commands, I want to blame who did those. I checked help page about `git reflog`, `git blame` and `git log`, no useful documentation related are found.

Note: this is different from `git commit` date but the `git` general operations' trigger time.

Any ideas?

Comment: `time git fetch` and `time git rebase`?

Comment: @ElpieKay Not the elapsed time, it's exact UTC time.

Comment: As I know, git commands don't have any options to print the time.

Comment: @ElpieKay I knew bash `history` support the custom formats with datetime but it doesn't cover the command from script file. It would be helpful if git does it, too.

Comment: For those in the scripts, how about printing timestamps before the commands to a log file?

Comment: @ElpieKay yes, I thought that too, but my embedded scripts used in [hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/manual/hazel/hazel-overview/) doesn't a standard log file for that, I don't want a hard log file path, either, so I prefer not using that.

Comment: Oh! I found a simple log stack entry in that hazel, resolved my case basically. Thanks @ElpieKay

Comment: Git itself doesn't track when such commands are executed. You could go spelunking in the file system and try to figure out what the time would be depending on when some file was created on disk or last written to but it is by no means accurate. If you are using a server-based remote, there might be logs on that server that could tell you when you or someone else last did a fetch. For rebases you probably need to look at the new commits. In short, there is no good way to get what you need.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen git reflog records sha id and operation descriptions, the corresponding date time should exist for them, too. It's proved by the following corrected answer, anyway.

Comment: So I looked at my local reflog, did a git fetch, then checked reflog, it didn't change. What am I missing? Or was the question just poorly worded in terms of what OP actually wanted?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen If you check the reflog of the remote tracking branch, you should be able to see git fetch operations: `git reflog --date=iso -10 origin/master`. Note, however, that the reflog only shows when refs are updated, so if your remote tracking branch was already up to date prior to running `git fetch`, that particular execution of `git fetch` will not show in the reflog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git records information about when refs in your local repo are updated in the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

For example, you can view the 10 latest commits pointed to by the HEAD pointer (ie. the history of which commits have been checked out in your local worktree) by:

```
git reflog --date=iso -10
```

You can view the 10 latest commits pointed to by a local branch by doing for example:

```
git reflog --date=iso -10 master
```

You can view the 10 latest commits pointed to by a remote tracking branch by doing:
(This is especially useful if you want to see when you ran fetch operations)

```
git reflog --date=iso -10 origin/master
```

**Note 1:** `git reflog` command lists all commands which change the commit pointed to by a branch head or the repo HEAD (not only rebases/fetches will be shown, also e.g. `git commit`)
**Note 2:** Reflog entries expire and are deleted after some time, so if the operations you want to investigate are too old, maybe the information is not available any more.

Comment: That's completely what I am looking for, thanks! I'm confused why this option isn't documented in the `reflog`'s help page.

Comment: `git reflog --help` states "**git reflog show** accepts any of the options accepted by **git log**". `--date` option is documented in `git log --help`. There, you can see the other supported date formats.